# How to get back the elements of array which are not defined in an index array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, vectorization

For example, I have following array in MATLAB:

```
a = 11:20 ;
```

and I want to to extract the elements from `a` which are not defined among the below index elements:

```
b = [2,3,5];
```

If I execute the following line of get:

```
a(b)

ans =

    12    13    15
```

I am looking for a method which is just opposite of above and without introducing loop to get the elements from `a` and index of those elements is not present in index array `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setdiff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) is the function that you're looking for.

```
a(setdiff(1:end,b))
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach:

```
>> a = 11:20;
>> b = [2,3,5];
>> c = a;
>> c(b) = []
c =
   11   14   16   17   18   19   20
```

`c(b)=[]` deletes from `c` the elements indexed by `b`.